# Strange graphical issues on PS3 - Tony Hawk Project 8

Tags: ps3, hdmi, tony-hawks-project-8

I am running into a strange graphical issue on Tony Hawk Project 8 for PS3 which makes it essentially unplayable.

In Career Mode or Free Skate mode, the graphics appear correct over a 180-degree range but are a jumbled mess over the other 180 degree.  I have tried in numerous spots (including wide-open areas) so I'm sure the issue is not due to a graphical / camera interaction in a particular location.

I can include a picture of the jumbled graphics later if it will help.  It is very colorful with lots of very thin, long triangles.  When you rotate the camera, the jumbled graphics move.  It looks like a messed-up kaleidoscope with no symmetry.

Other graphical overlays (manual meter, grind meter, trick/point messages, etc) show up fine even when the graphics are a mess.
Tutorial mode and various menus work correctly.

I have 3 other games which all work correctly.  (Dynasty Warriors 8, Dynasty Warriors Strikeforce, and DBZ Raging Blast 2). DVDs also work. Therefore, I originally figured it must be a problem with the disc. However, a 2nd copy of Tony Hawk Project 8 showed exactly the same problem. This seems like an important clue but I don't know what it means.

I am using the HDMI connection with 1080i graphics mode.  (My TV does not support 1080p).  I also tried under 720p and got the same results as 1080i.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I think these are symptoms of an overheating/dying PS3. I get these all the time when I play Skyrim/Fallout3 or other GPU/CPU intensive games. :(

Comment: agree with Biff, sounds like a hardware issue, to confirm, try the disk in any other ps3 if you can

Comment: Would it still be a hardware issue if other (newer) games work though?

Comment: @MikeR sure, gpu architecture is vastly complex, some modules and features are only used in some games, and the way developers choose to use the provided SDKs vary as well, this is why emulator developers have a hard time getting different games to work

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer I was able to confirm that the game works in another PS3.  I guess I need to look through some of the other articles on here to see how to fix my system.